# PHP read file instead of download

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

If a web page forces through the headers the download of a file. Example shown below!

trying_to_parse.php:

```
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="examplefile.xml"');
 header('Content-type: "text/xml"; charset="utf8"');
 readfile('examplefile.xml');
```

Using php im attempting to grab and parse this file by:

example.php:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'trying_to_parse.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
echo $xml;
curl_close($ch);
```

This did not work because with curl their are no headers.

So i went ahead and tried a few more thing like fopen and file_get_... and these also did not work.

Any ideas on how to actually load a file that is being forced through the headers to download?

I want to use:

```
$dom->loadXML($xml);
```

But ill take anything :)

I want to parse the ForceDownloadedFile.xml file that is force downloaded when you visit a URL. Any idea?

Comment: Please contact that website vendor for API access.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request for a third party website.

Comment: Nope its a general question You just fail to see that and like spamming post! Edited it so people like you can see that more easily!

Comment: *"No luck...."* remains undefined in your question, please keep it to the programming domain and express what you've got expected and what you've got as well. Also curl is always downloading, and technically in HTTP there are no headers that are forcing downloading with curl. Therefore your question remains very unclear. It still sounds a lot that you want something to do which is generally not clear what that is (as far as the programming domain is concerned) and instead you only give some broad description of an issue you have with a specific website. See as well Marc B's comments.

Comment: Also please contact the vendor of that website if your suggested use is an actual option in using that website. You might hit something here that is provoked per it's TOS.

Comment: I made a small edit again for you because you still cant see the question! would you like a JFiddle so you can get the question?

Comment: Don't confuse "not seeing the question" with having a question that is off-topic. In any case you should add an example that shows your issue *in your question* so that what you describe can be easily reproduced. That is generally suggested when posting a question. Just go ahead, add some code that allows to reproduce your issue. This can help to provide further feedback.

Comment: Again made some correction for you! Do you see the valid question yet?

Comment: Don't confuse headers with response body. Even thought response headers and bodies are the *download* (as Marc B pointed out hours ago), this still does not qualify for maintaining a difference to explicitly mention. You're confusing getting some dialog offered with actually doing the programming. It's time you take care now understanding what a protocol and the HTTP protocol in specific is .- RFCs document this ***since ages***.

Comment: If you don't know how to answer the question avoid commenting!

Comment: You can fail with style and you can fail the ordinary way. Believe me, the internets are unforgiving.

Comment: I already have the solution I'm amused by your continued effort to block any attempt at knowledge being shared! keep up the work one day someone will come here looking for the same thing and due to your deliberate attempt to stop this process will have to go else where! keep it up! Your failing the idea of this place. Id post the answer but because my question is on hold and not about programming apparently ill refrain from doing so because that would be constructive unlike your post.

Comment: where is your formulated answer? Why don't you offer it for voting against Marc B's ones? (closed 14hrs ago, I don't say you're not eager. Go for it!)

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming, within the scope defined in the help center

Answer (score 0):

That's a 301 redirect, so you need to tell curl to follow that redirect, and fetch the file from the new location:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: setopt you mean. This doesn't allow the reading or downloading of the file.

Comment: no, but it'll allow curl to follow the redirect chain until it gets to a url that DOES serve up some data. with the option off, curl will stop dead in its tracks on the first url, because it's not allow to go where google's response is telling it to.

Comment: On the redirect page the file still downloads and on the subsequent page it does as well. The content is never served on the page that's the problem. I cant figure out away to fetch the file that google is trying to force download when i visit the page.

Comment: take out `echo $xml`, then? you've got returntransfer on, so there's no way curl will output anything to whatever's running this script, unless you do it yourself.

Comment: Im not sure how this helps me grab the file that is force downloading through headers

Comment: curl couldn't care less about download headers. its job is just to fetch the url you told it to, and return that data as a string. the force-downloader headers are HINTS to a browser that it should present a 'save as' dialogue, but the browser is free to ignore that and just render/display the data instead.

Comment: I want to download the file. SO curl is not what im looking to use?

Comment: "download" is a loaded word. **EVERYTHING** you do with a browser on the web is a download. I usually say download when I mean "get a file from somewhere and save it to disk". Your code appears to just be fetching a url's data and trying to pass it to DOM. that is a download, but it's not involving a file.

Comment: I want to parse the Download.xml file that is force downloaded when you visit the URL above. Any idea?